# How do I prevent the memory loose from unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

This code below will result in memory loss because rA is initialized as invalid when it is constructed. When can I do to fix this problem?

Use shared_ptr or hope for future compiler versions to catch this bad code?

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct A {};
void use(const A& a) {};

unique_ptr<A> foo()
{
    unique_ptr<A> pa(new A());
    return pa;
}

int main()
{
    const A& rA = *foo(); // rA is unusable, initialized with invalid reference (invalidated by destruction of temporary unique_ptr returned from foo)
    use(rA);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What do you mean by "loose"?

Comment: The temporary object is destroyed at the end of the statement (the semicolon), and you have a dangling reference.

Comment: "loose" = "loss", presumably.

Comment: Your question has a false premise. `rA` is never constructed, since it's a reference. A reference to an object that's destroyed at the end of the statement. Take out the `&` and it will happily survive to be used again.

Comment: I added a code comment to clarify the problem and show where we get undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't see how using a shared_ptr will help you. If you use a reference to a temporary variable that no-longer exists, things will go bad.

Comment: No. The unique_ptr that goes out of scope has already *moved* its contents to the return value. The error is in your binding a reference to the *dereferenced* return value. Instead of extending the lifetime of the unique_ptr you bind to the thing it points to and the unique_ptr managing its life-time gets destroyed immediately after

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rewrite your `main` as:

```
int main()
{
   auto a = foo();

   use(*a);
}
```

As an aside I would rewrite `foo` as:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> foo()
{
    return std::make_unique<A>();
}
```

Comment: Why do you "return std::move(pa);"? it gets evaluated back to "return pa;"

Comment: `return std::move...` can break NRVO.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter, yes you're right, I've updated the answer - didn't realise std::move could prevent the compiler from an optimisation step - thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you return objects *by value* you return a *temporary* that will get destroyed *immediately* unless it is copied or bound to a variable from the caller's side.

What you are doing wrong is binding a reference to something the returned temporary object *contains* and not the returned object itself. By the time you access the thing you have bound a reference to it has been deleted by the temporary object's destructor when it was destroyed.

To illustrate what you are doing wrong I have written an equivalent example using a `std::vector` and binding a reference to one of its elements:

```
void use(const int& a) {}

std::vector<int> foo()
{
    return {1, 2, 3};
}

int main()
{
    const int& rA = foo()[0]; // bind to an element
    // the vector itself is destroyed by the time we get here

    use(rA); // whoops using a reference to an element from a destroyed vector
}
```

Comment: So the compiler should ideally see that that alias I am setting (by having a reference to the returned vector) means that the vector can't go out of scope yet? Ideally the compiler should complain at compile time.

Comment: @Damian It would be nice if the compiler complained, but maybe its not so easy for the compiler to know that you are doing something wrong. There may be legitimate code that looks like this and the compiler can't tell between them. After all how does the compiler know that the object you bind to will be destroyed when the vector is destroyed?

Comment: I guess it would know if I use referred to the result directly via this vector<int> v = foo() in this way it is still in scope. But I am not sure how the compiler would complain when we are just taking a reference / alias.